# Nginx configuration leads to endless redirect loop

Tags: ssl, nginx, password, ruby-on-rails

So I've looked at every sample configuration I could find and yet every time I try and view a page that requires ssl, I end up in an redirect loop. I'm running nginx/0.8.53 and passenger 3.0.2.

Here's the ssl config

```
server  {
  listen 443 default ssl;
  server_name <redacted>.com www.<redacted>.com;
  root /home/app/<redacted>/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;  
  ssl_certificate      /home/app/ssl/<redacted>.com.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key  /home/app/ssl/<redacted>.key;

  proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header  X_FORWARDED_PROTO https;
  proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header  Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header  X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
  proxy_redirect    off;
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

  location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(/.*)?$ http://blog.<redacted>.com/$1 permanent;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
      expires      max;
      break;
    }
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
}
```

Here's the non-ssl config

```
server  {
  listen 80;
  server_name <redacted>.com www.<redacted>.com;
  root /home/app/<redacted>/public;
  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env production;  

  location /blog {
    rewrite ^/blog(/.*)?$ http://blog.<redacted>.com/$1 permanent;
  }

  location ~* \.(js|css|jpg|jpeg|gif|png)$ {
    if (-f $request_filename) {
      expires      max;
      break;
    }
  }

  error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
    root   html;
  }
}
```

Let me know if there's any additional info I can give to help diagnose the issue.

Comment: What is an example URL you are requesting?  What are the exact headers returned by the server?  Curl (or telnet, or LiveHTTPHeaders for Firefox) is your friend.

Comment: ok, did that and here's what I got https://gist.github.com/2831f092b0be1476e708. It looks like the cookie is set to http only, could that be an issue? New to setting up and configuring ssl. I also tried changing the configuration as follows: https://gist.github.com/ce19ff0e50a35703278c

Comment: The presence of the Phusion header and the cookie suggest that it is Rails or your app that is generating the redirect.  Have a look in the rails log.

Comment: The text of the redirect entity body looks like Rails, not nginx.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your app isn't able to detect it's running on https and redirects to the https URL again and again.

Usually https is detected based on `HTTPS` environment variable, and passenger module for nginx allows to set one with [passenger_set_cgi_param](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#_passenger_set_cgi_param_lt_cgi_environment_name_gt_lt_value_gt) directive. Adding something like

```
passenger_set_cgi_param  HTTPS  on;
```

into the https server{} block should help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the *proxy_set_header* directives should be put in to the *location* sections.

Try using:

```
...
location / {
    # needed for SSL
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-Url-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    # Each of those lines may cause an infinate redirect loop
    #proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED_PROTO https;
    #proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    # This two may break the redirection when on ssl
    #proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    #proxy_redirect off;
...
```

At least this works for me on a quite hard to setup environment with haproxy in front of nginx.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: The `proxy_set_header` directive is allowed at http, server and location levels, see http://nginx.org/r/proxy_set_header. But as the config doesn't use proxy_pass at all (but uses passenger module instead) - it's completely useless here.